# How should I display a constant notification in Android?

Tags: android

I need to notify the user of my app if the app is connected to the server. If it is, show an online icon, text, etc. somewhere in the app. What is the suggested UI guidelines for this type of notification?

Please note that I don't need help finding out if I'm connected or not, I just need help with the UI guidelines.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked out [this yet?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: This really belongs on ux.SE

Comment: @Asok, I have. Although I called it a notification, I don't think it should be an Android Notification as it is only a visual representation to the user of whether they are connected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a constant notification icon but you actually need a status bar icon.

Go through this doc

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

Answer (score 0):

just set the ongoing flag to be true
like this:

NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(...);
nBuilder.setOngoing(true);